# Production version with electron-forge does not work

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm using electron, specifically "electron-forge" to turn my project into a desktop app; I am using javascript, I have also used next.js, react.js and my app is connected to my database which is MySQL, it uses dynamic pages, the build is executed with next, now electron indicates that the starting point of my app is the file "main.js" in the root of my project, there it indicates the creation of a window and there normally goes an index.html, which in my case for development I have replaced by "http://localhost:3000/" which is where my app runs, the problem that once I run the "yarn make" my final app (.exe) opens that route when it starts and obviously it's wrong because since there is no process running on that port it shows "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED", I want to know what I should put in that route or where is what should be read by it (in case when executing the next build it has been generated), the code of my main is this, please help:

```
const path = require('path');
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    minWidth: 960,
    minHeight: 720,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });

  // Cargar el archivo index.html generado por Next.js
  mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:3000/");

};

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();

  app.on('activate', () => {
    
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
  });
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit();
});
```

I tried to put the path of the file that the build generates with next, specifically "..next\server\pages\index.html" but what resulted from this is that the electron window that opened showed me code